# Conversion of default arguments not considered during overload selection?

Tags: c++, type-conversion, language-lawyer, overload-resolution, default-arguments

I was trying to write a straightforward solution to this question: [array decay to pointer and overload resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21972652/103167)

Clearly in the original, both overloads have equal conversion strength (exact match), so the non-template is preferred.  Indeed, if I change the other to a template, the call become ambiguous:

```
struct stg
{
    template<typename T = void>
    stg(const char* const& c_str, T* = 0);

    template<int N>
    stg(const char (&str) [N]);
};
```

So I wanted to introduce a user-defined conversion, which would be strictly worse than the exact match of the second overload.

```
struct stg
{
    template<typename> struct cvt { operator int() { return 0;} };

    template<typename T = void>
    stg(const char* const& c_str, int = cvt<T>());

    template<int N>
    stg(const char (&str) [N]);
};
```

But [g++ says this is still ambiguous](http://ideone.com/XaPCMQ).  Why does the user-defined conversion in the default argument not affect overload ranking?

Comment: I thought default arguments are ignored for overload resolution?

Comment: @dyp: Seems like you think right.  Can you cite the rule that makes it so?  That would be an answer.

Answer (score 4):

[over.match.viable]/2 (from >n3797, github 5f7cb4)

> First, to be a viable function, a candidate function shall have enough
>   parameters to agree in number with the arguments in the list.
>
> - If there are *m* arguments in the list, all candidate functions having
>     exactly *m* parameters are viable.
> - A candidate function having fewer
>     than *m* parameters is viable only if it has an ellipsis in its
>     parameter list (8.3.5). For the purposes of overload resolution, any
>     argument for which there is no corresponding parameter is considered
>     to “match the ellipsis” (13.3.3.1.3).
> - A candidate function having more than *m* parameters is viable only if the *(m+1)*-st parameter has a
>     default argument (8.3.6). **For the purposes of overload resolution, the parameter list is truncated on the right, so that there are exactly *m* parameters.**

[emphasis mine]

Comment: I like how your emphasis is exactly like mine :)

Comment: @jrok: It isn't any longer, he has italics now :-)