# Template type-deduction performs implicit array-to-pointer conversion

Tags: c++, c++11

I've read existing questions about this standard conversion.
However, I didn't find a satisfying answer.

I have this piece of code which shows that the `T*` overload is chosen over the `T&&` one. From what I understood, the forwarding reference overload should bind everything, unless another overload is a perfect match.

In the following code, `tab` is a `char const(&)[4]`.

Could someone explain to me why the array-to-pointer conversion is performed here?
And if there is a way to workaround that conversion, I'm all ears!

(coliru [link](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8427df5649fcc241))

```
#include <utility>

template <typename T>
void f(T&& lol)
{
}

template <typename T>
void f(T* pof)
{
  static_assert(sizeof(T) && false, "");
}

template <typename T>
struct S;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  decltype("lol") tab = "lol";
  S<decltype(tab)> s;
  f("lol");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Related/duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28182838, http://stackoverflow.com/q/21972652.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Arrays are deduced to Ptr types.

see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction

> Before deduction begins, the following adjustments to P and A are
>   made:
>
> 1) If P is not a reference type,
>
> a) if A is an array type, A is replaced by the pointer type obtained from array-to-pointer conversion;
>
> b) otherwise, if A is a function type, A is replaced by the pointer type obtained from function-to-pointer conversion;
>
> c)otherwise, if A is a cv-qualified type, the top-level cv-qualifiers are ignored for deduction

Comment: Weird thing is, even after adding a `T const(&)[N]` overload, it fails to compile, saying the call is ambiguous. Is there no way to differentiate between pointers and array at all?

Comment: You can try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28182838/is-it-possible-to-overload-a-function-that-can-tell-a-fixed-array-from-a-pointer

Comment: Well, both proposed workarounds work. Very tricky but that suits me

Comment: This is misleading. In the OP's example, in one of the alternatives `P` *is* a reference type, meaning that for that alternative the array is NOT deduced as pointer type. That's the essence of the question.

Comment: @AnT the compiler chooses 1 of the 2 template overloads. In the example there is only one template instantiation and that is a an array. So this means the compiler thinks the pointer overload is the more specific one. Which seems to work as intended by the standard. And if there is anything misleading: I basically just quoted cppreference. If there is something misleading there you should talk with them or the c++ standard committee. If I missed something fundamental here (which can happen) I am always eager to learn new things. You could also just provide your own better answer too.

Answer (score 3):

A single-argument function template `f` is considered more specialized than a template `g` if an arbitrary type corresponding to the argument of `f` can be deduced to the argument of `g`, but not vice versa.

An arbitrary pointer type `T*` can be deduced to `T&&`, but this does not hold in the reverse direction (`T&&` cannot be deduced to `T*` in the general case), so `f(T*)` is considered more specialized than `f(T&&)`.

To resolve this, we have to make `f(T*)` less attractive to the compiler, for example using SFINAE:

```
template <typename U,
    typename T = std::enable_if_t<std::is_pointer<U>::value, std::remove_pointer_t<U>>>
void f(U const& pof)  // U == T*
```